# Square Images in FlowListview (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, image, xaml, xamarin

I want to create a FlowListView that has an equal number of rows and columns and it contains images that has the same height and width. However, FlowListView distorts the height of the rows so that it is not equal to the width of the columns. How can I bind the width of the columns to RowHeight (something like the following)?

```
<controls:FlowListView RowHeight="{Binding ColumnWidth}" ...>
    <controls:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Image ... />
      </DataTemplate>
    </controls:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
</controls:FlowListView>
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I did this in code rather than in Xaml as I found it easier to apply but it should be something similar (and there's probably a better way than mine).

I set the 'HasUnevenRows' property to true on the FlowListView control.

```
Flow = new FlowListView()
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            FlowColumnCount = 3,
            FlowColumnTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(FlowCellImage)),
            FlowTappedBackgroundDelay = 250,
            FlowTappedBackgroundColor = Color.Gray,
            SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.Default,
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true,
            HasUnevenRows = true,
            //Margin = thickness
        };
```

Then on the Image I set the 'HeightRequest' property to be 'Application.Current.MainPage.Width / 3' as my row had 3 pictures in it.

```
public class FlowCellImage : FlowViewCell
    {
        private Image ImgPost;
        public FlowCellImage()
        {
            ImgPost = new Image
            {
                Aspect = Aspect.AspectFill
            };
            ImgPost.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "ThumbnailUrl");

            HeightRequest = Application.Current.MainPage.Width / 3;
            Content = ImgPost;
        }
    }
```